# ad thumbnail to aw blog posts in magento

Tags: html, magento-1.8, php

in magento 1.8.1 i have added a thumbnail image to `aw blog` posts header and into the aw blog sidebar widget next to the each headline

i did these:

> In app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Manage/Blog/Edit/Form.php

change:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
    'id' => 'edit_form',
    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
    'method' => 'post',
 ));
```

to

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
    'id' => 'edit_form',
    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
    'method' => 'post',
    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
 ));
```

> In app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Manage/Blog/Edit/Tab/Form.php

add

```
$fieldset->addField('featured_image', 'image', array(
    'name' => 'featured_image',
    'label' => 'Featured Image'
));
```

below the line

```
$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('blog_form', array('legend' => Mage::helper('blog')->__('Post information')));
```

> In app/code/community/AW/Blog/controllers/Manage/BlogController.php

add

```
if(isset($_FILES['featured_image']['name']) and (file_exists($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name']))) {
   try {
      $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('featured_image');
      $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
      $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

      // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file in a folder the magento way
      // setAllowRenameFiles(true) -> move your file directly in the $path folder
      $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

      $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS .'blogpic'.DS;

      $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['featured_image']['name']);

      $data['featured_image'] = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
   }catch(Exception $e) {

   }
}

// handle delete image
else {
   if(isset($data['featured_image']['delete']) && $data['featured_image']['delete'] == 1)
      $data['image_main'] = '';
   else
      unset($data['featured_image']);
}
```

below the line

```
$model = Mage::getModel('blog/post');
```

And added a "featured_image" column to the aw_blog table in database. Use the type VARCHAR(255) default null and null enable .

and add

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$post->getFeaturedImage() ?>" alt="featuredImage" />
```

to

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/aw_blog/blog.phtml

below line

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="postWrapper">
        <div class="postTitle">
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a></h2>
```

the problem is: the images are saving in right place in `media/blogpic` but they are not shown in frontend

Comment: Open developer console in browser and take a look at `featuredImage`’s image source attr.

Comment: @mudasobwa its loading from `mdeia` (base media dir in root), but it should load from `media/blogpic`

Comment: Add `. DS . 'blogpic' . DS .` to `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)` when `echo`?

Comment: @mudasobwa im new in coding but i have tried this one:
`$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . "blogpic";`
and again same problem!
i will thankful if you explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `blog.phtml` subst

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$post->getFeaturedImage() ?>" alt="featuredImage" />
```

with

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).DS.'blogpic'.DS.$post->getFeaturedImage() ?>" alt="featuredImage" />
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add a featured image or thumbnail image to the Magento version of AWBlog without coding is as follows:

-In the blog post go to the **SHORT CONTENT** text field

-In that field enter your image url

```
<img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/blogimages/myimages/your.jpg"}}" alt="folding chairs" />
```

-Underneath that enter your blurb that shows

When you save and open the blog post in the blog overview you will see you featured image shows with the content blurb just below it.